C# WebSocket Server not responding to pings
I've managed to write a csharp websocket server and clients can connect, however the clients send a ping message but the server doesnt respond with a pong so the client drops the connection.
On further investigation, it turns out I need to have a ReadAsync running to capture the ping message, but then it's in an await state so blocks everything!
I would love to get to the underlying socket so I could do a socket.available to check for read data but thats not possible.
So how are you supposed to write a websocket server in c# (and dont say SignalR!) that responds to a ping and can determine if the client has dropped!
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static async Task ClientHandler(HttpContext context)
    {
        using WebSocket socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Websocket client connected from {0}", socket.SubProtocol);

        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        WebSocketReceiveResult payload = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        string? message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", message);

        // workaround for replying to ping from client which requires ReceiveAsync to be active
        // Task.Run(async () =>
        // {
        //     await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        // });

        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message...");
            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
            await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(msg, 0, msg.Length), payload.MessageType, true, CancellationToken.None);

            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "No more messages", CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var app = WebApplication.CreateBuilder().Build();

        app.UseWebSockets();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/")
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                    await ClientHandler(context);
                else
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            else
                await next(context);
        });

        app.Run("http://127.0.0.1:8001");
    }
}


check this code:
class Program
{
    static async Task ClientHandler(HttpContext context)
    {
        using WebSocket socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket client connected.");

        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

        // Task to continuously receive messages
        var receiveTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closing", CancellationToken.None);
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket client disconnected.");
                }
                else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                {
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", message);
                }
                else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Binary)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received binary message of length: {0}", result.Count);
                }
                 
            }
        });

        // Task to continuously send messages
        var sendTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
                await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(msg, 0, msg.Length), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.Delay(200);
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAny(receiveTask, sendTask);

        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket connection closed.");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseWebSockets();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
            {
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    await ClientHandler(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await next(context);
            }
        });

        app.Run("http://127.0.0.1:8001");
// or app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:8001");

    }
}

Solution no.2: You can use Fleck library
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        // Start Fleck WebSocket server
        StartWebSocketServer();

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

    private static void StartWebSocketServer()
    {
        var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:8181");

        server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () => Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
            socket.OnClose = () => Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected!");
            socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + message);
                socket.Send("Echo: " + message);
            };
        });

        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket server started on ws://0.0.0.0:8181");
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
}


you have WebSocketMessageType.Close twice in solution 1

@Christian Yeah , my bad. I edited that.
